# space between in ConstrainedBox

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

There are two rows in a ConstrainedBox. And two widgets in first row and then i want to present them space between. Only one widget in second row and its size always not the same(like text in chat).
The problem is length of first row didn't follow second row, how to solve it? Thanks!

[image: first row not space between]

```
ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300 ) ,
      child:  Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
         Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
             Flexible(child: const Text("Flutter")),
             const Image(image: NetworkImage("https://penueling.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/flutter.jpg"), width: 40, height: 20,),
            ],
          ),
             const Text("1111111111111"),
        ],
      ))
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a Spacer element in your column? I can also suggest trying to change the mainAxisAlignment of the Column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) and [`Positioned`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) widgets to achieve this layout. Basically you make a `Column`  and above that you add the image in a `Stack`, then you instruct the image to go to the top right position.

Something like this (I used an icon for the example):

```
ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: const BoxConstraints(
      maxWidth: 300,
    ),
    child: Stack(children: [
      Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: const [Text("Flutter"), Text('1111111111111')]),
      const Positioned(
          top: 0, right: 0, child: Icon(Icons.person, size: 16))
    ])),
```

This can cause problem for you if the bottom text occupies less space then the `Flutter` text. If this can happen, you can add another constraint to `BoxConstraints`:

```
minWidth: 100,
```